# Nagios reporting localhost statistics instead of remote machine

Tags: nagios

I'm a little baffled by this - I set up Nagios3's server process on one machine (**tala**) and NPRE on two others (**medea** and **iiyanara**.), and thought it was set up correctly. For various frustrating reasons I had to rebuild **medea** from a disk image, and as a result NPRE isn't installed anymore.

Imagine my surprise when Nagios is (days later) continuing to merrily report not only that my server is up, but also a series of performance metrics like total processes, etc. As it turns out, I'm pretty sure the Nagios instance has actually been reporting on localhost for both **medea** and **iiyanara** all along.

Here's the initial block + first service block from medea.conf:

```
define host{
    use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
    host_name               medea.phyre.im
    alias                   Medea
    address                 97.107.128.112
    }

define service{
    use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name                       medea.phyre.im
    service_description             Disk Space
    check_command                   check_all_disks!20%!10%
}
```

Curiously, if I specify a different IP, Nagios reports that the machine is down. So either:

1. Nagios is using black sorcery to commune with **medea** despite a total absence of the NPRE service
2. Nagios is reporting on localhost for some reason

...And then it STOPS doing those things if I specify, for instance, 197.107.128.112 as the target IP.

My question is basically this: what the hell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_all_disks` probably uses `check_disk` plugin which check amount of used space of locally mounted filesystems.

You should use something like:

```
check_nrpe!check_all_disks
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Wow do I feel dumb. Thanks a mint :)

Answer (score 0):

Check
http://www.kernelhardware.org/nagios-nrpe-to-monitor-remote-linux-server/

In short
For disk check & CPU check
in /etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg add the following

```
# for nrpe check_disk plugin
define command{
        command_name    check_disk
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
        }   

# for nrpe check_load plugin
define command{
        command_name    check_load
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
        }
```

in /etc/nagios/objects/localhost.cfg where server1

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       server1
        service_description             Root Partition
        check_command                   check_disk!check_disk
        contact_groups                  admins
        }
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       server1
        service_description             Current Load
        check_command                   check_load!check_load
        contact_groups                  admins
        }
```

check if config is ok with

```
#nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg
```

reload the nagios

```
#/etc/rc.d/rc.nagios reload
```